# how to expand columns from web scraping?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape a site with tis code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import numpy as np

url = 'https://www.quantalys.com/Categories'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = soup.select_one("#DataCatsWithPerfs")["value"]
data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

but when I tried to print the df (just the last 2 columns), I get:

```
dtRetMonth  perfCalendaire
0   2023-07-01  [{'nYear': 2015, 'nRet': 0.1204}, {'nYear': 20...
1   2023-07-01  [{'nYear': 2015, 'nRet': 0.143}, {'nYear': 201...
2   2023-07-01  [{'nYear': 2015, 'nRet': 0.2041}, {'nYear': 20...
3   2023-07-01  [{'nYear': 2015, 'nRet': 0.0155}, {'nYear': 20...
4   2023-07-01  [{'nYear': 2015, 'nRet': -0.1601}, {'nYear': 2...
```

How to expand the perfCalendaire columns into '2015', '2016',...columns ?

I would like to expand columns after web scraping operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.quantalys.com/Categories'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = soup.select_one("#DataCatsWithPerfs")["value"]
data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for item in row['perfCalendaire']:
       
        year = str(item['nYear'])
        df.loc[index, year] = item['nRet']

df = df.drop(columns=['perfCalendaire'])

df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

print(df)
```

[image]

```
years_columns = [str(year) for year in range(2015, 2022)]
print(df[years_columns])
```

[image]

Comment: it is strange because perf_calendaire has 47 columns whereas I was expecting around 8 ????

Comment: what's strange ?

Comment: is seems not to work because when I do df.drop(axis=1, how='all') I get a lot of #na value whereas I was expecting value for 2015...2021

Comment: in your new df perfCalendaire you loose the index of the previous dataframe (id)